# how to make Terminal (unix) use Microsoft Outlook instead of Apple Mail

Tags: terminal, mail.app, ms-office

We use Microsoft Outlook at work so I need to be able to use Microsoft Outlook instead of Apple's Mail program when I invoke it in Bash. Can anyone help me associate programs inside of Bash?

Comment: How do you invoke Apple Mail from within Terminal?

Comment: Can you show an example of the bash script you are using now?

Answer (score 1):

To activate Outlook from Bash (assuming normal install):

```
open /Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011/Microsoft\ Outlook.app
```

What did you want to do with it beyond that?